# avoid AccessViolationException when calling c code

Tags: c#, c, dllimport, access-violation

i am using c# to call a c code through a DLL , i got AccessViolationException when calling a method , here is the code from the source header

```
extern __declspec( dllexport )
int ReadCardSN( IN OUT unsigned char* CardSN );
```

in my c# code i am using

```
public static byte[] Data = new byte[4];
[DllImport("CardLib.dll")]
public static extern Int32 ReadCardSN(byte[] Data);
int resCode = ReadCardSN(Data);
```

what can be the problem ?

Comment: Is the calling convention right? Do you really only need to allocate 4 bytes.

Comment: yes it's a buffer of 4 bytes

Comment: And the calling convention?

Comment: it's right too i guess , see the declaration above from the source header file

Comment: That looks like cdecl to me. Not that it would explain the error. Find some working example C++ code.

Comment: here is some working code in c 

`#define DATA_BLOCK_SIZE 10240
unsigned char Data[DATA_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0};
  unsigned int DataLen = DATA_BLOCK_SIZE;
// Read card serial number
        PRINT_MSG( "Reading sn..." );
        RESET_BUFFER( Data, DataLen );
        Result = ReadCardSN( Data );
        if( Result == NO_ERROR )
            PRINT_BUFFER( "Card SN: ", Data, 4 );
        PRINT_ERROR( Result );`

Comment: That code should appear in the question. 10240 is quite definitely larger than 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because your buffer is too small. The example code shows the use of a buffer of length 10240. You supply a buffer of length 4.

As written it looks like the C code uses the default cdecl calling convention. Your C# code uses stdcall.

It would also be better to apply the `[In, Out]` attribute to the argument. Because `byte[]` is blittable that is not strictly necessary but it is semantically accurate.

Comment: i just want to mention that the c code is calling the DLL too , so how can i fix my c# code ? i still get the same error 

`public static byte[] Data = new byte[1024];
[DllImport("CardLib.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Int32 ReadCardSN(byte[] Data);
int resCode = ReadCardSN(Data);`

Comment: 1024 is less than 10240